# Beginner in Rspec. Where is the default directory?

Tags: ruby, rspec

very quick question. I'm just learning to use Ruby/ruby on rails/Rspec, and I have NO prior knowledge to all of this so it's quite difficult. With respect to Rspec and running tests.. Every resource keeps saying "use the lib directory". What directory is that? Where is it? I'm using Windows. Could someone tell me THE EXACT PATH AND LOCATION for that directory? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: This is going to depend on which Ruby distribution you're using, among other things.  Include some more details about how you installed Ruby, and which IDE you're using, if any.  There's nothing consistent about the various Ruby options available in Windows.  You might be better off starting out with RubyMine or some other more-complete solution which will allow you to add RSpec from within the UI and should make it easier to get started and locate things.

Answer (score 2):

Many projects that use Rspec lay out their projects like so:

```
my_project
+ lib
  - some_library.rb
+ spec
  - spec_helper.rb
  - lib
    - some_library_spec.rb
  ...other files, directories...
```

So the `lib` directory just refers to the `my_project/lib/` directory above. It is automatically added to the Ruby `$LOAD_PATH` by RSpec for convenience, which is why people typically put their Ruby modules in that directory (if it exists).

Comment: This is a Unixy answer; OP is using Windows.

Comment: I wouldn't expect the basic file structure to be different... are you aware of any differences I should point out? Backslashes instead of forward...?

Comment: Yes, backslashes instead of forward for a start.  OP also wants the full path, so I'm guessing they need to find the root of the project first.

Comment: The exact path doesn't matter since its relative to the current working directory from which they are running `rspec` (and I have no I way of answering without them telling me what directory they are in)

Comment: And how about a compromise on the backward/forwardslashes and go with `-`/`+` :)